# How to get a configuration value with a SELECT in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there any possibility to get a configuration value with a select in Postgres?
For example smthng like this?

```
SELECT max_locks_per_transaction from config_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [`current_setting()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET)

```
select current_setting('max_locks_per_transaction');
```

Or select from [`pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-settings.html)

```
select *
from pg_settings
where name = 'max_locks_per_transaction'
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler - just use `SHOW`:

```
> SHOW max_locks_per_transaction
64
```